# make a booking - For loop

Tags: java

I'm not sure if I'm doing the for loop correctly to give a true value in the if statement.
 How do i increment by 1 if i need to use this kind of the for loop. This is the part I'm working on.

To make a booking, the user should be prompted to input the destination and day of week that they wish to travel. If such a flight exists and there are seats available on the flight, then the passenger details should be input and a new passenger created . The number of seats booked for the flight should be incremented by 1.

```
    public void flightBooking(){

    Passenger passenger;
    String    flightDay, flightDestination;
    boolean   found = false;
    Flight    myFlight = null;
    Scanner   scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println(" On which day do you wish to travel ? ");
    flightDay = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println(" What is your destination ? ");
    flightDestination = scan.nextLine();


    for ( Flight d  : flightList ) 
    {
        if (d.getDay().equals(flightDay))
        {
            myFlight= d;
            found = true;
        }

    }

    for ( Flight s  : flightList )
    {
        if (s.getDestination().equals(flightDestination))
        {
            myFlight= s;
            found = true;
        }

    }


    if (found == true)
    {
        System.out.println("The Flight Day and Destination were found, the Flight will be booked.");
        Passenger passengers = new Passenger ("Laura", "14 Rathmines Rd ","laura99@gmail.com" , myFlight);
        passengerList.add(passengers);

    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("There is no flight booking.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the optimized code

```
public void flightBooking(){

 Passenger passenger;
 String    flightDay, flightDestination;
 boolean   found = false;
 Flight    myFlight = null;
 Scanner   scan = new Scanner(System.in);


 System.out.println(" On which day do you wish to travel ? ");
 flightDay = scan.nextLine();

 System.out.println(" What is your destination ? ");
 flightDestination = scan.nextLine();


 for ( Flight d  : flightList ) 
 {
    if (d.getDay().equals(flightDay) && d.getDestination().equals(flightDestination))
    {
        System.out.println("The Flight Day and Destination were found, the Flight will be booked.");
    Passenger passengers = new Passenger ("Laura", "14 Rathmines Rd ","laura99@gmail.com" , myFlight);
    passengerList.add(passengers);
        found = true;
        break;
    }

 }

 if (found == false)
 {

    System.out.println("There is no flight booking.");
 }
}
```

In your code if the date does not match and the destination matches then also the booking will happen as adding two for loop were making it or condition however it should be and. Also it can be achieved by one for loop only.

Comment: I think you'd also need to put a `break` into the `if` statement within the `for-each` loop. Otherwise it could add the passenger to multiple flights.